# How to use Ext JS 4.0 with GXT

Tags: gwt, extjs, extjs4, gxt

Firstly I love GWT and GXT I'm a big fan. But GXT's functionality lags behind that of Ext JS 4.0.

Specifically I'd like to use the Ext JS 4.0 Buffered Scrolling grid within an app otherwise completely written in GXT.

I have little doubt that this is possible. My only question is... HOW?!

Answer (score 0):

Until GXT catches up to the version you require you only have two options...

1. Get latest build of GXT from Sencha and keep on the bleeding edge of GXT obviously not the most safest choice.
2. Manually combine the `BufferView` which is the buffering side of it And `LiveGridView` which loads on scroll, together to create what you want.